# Linker error: Template relational operator

Tags: c++, templates

Why does this code give me a linker error and how do I fix it?

**Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "operator==(foo const&, foo const&)", referenced from: _main in main.o ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture x86_64**

```
template<typename T>
class foo {
  //friends get access to the private member t
  friend bool operator==(const foo<T> &lhs, const foo<T> &rhs);
  T t;
};

template<typename T>
bool operator==(const foo<T> &lhs, const foo<T> &rhs) {
  return lhs.t == rhs.t;
}

int main(int,char**) {
  foo<int> f1, f2;
  if (f1 == f2)
    ;
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a fix of your code:

```
template<typename T>
class foo; // Forward declaration

template<typename T> // Need to define or declare this before the class
bool operator==(const foo<T> &lhs, const foo<T> &rhs) {
  return lhs.t == rhs.t; 
}

template<typename T>
class foo {
  // Notice the little <> here denoting a specialization
  friend bool operator==<>(const foo<T> &lhs, const foo<T> &rhs);
  T t;
};
```

Comment: Declaring the function first would suffice.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: `foo` is unknown before the class definition, you need the forward declaration or define within or after the class.

Comment: @JesseGood: I think Sebastian meant that it suffices to forward-declare `operator==`. Since it compiles either way, it's an open question whether that's necessary. +1, anyway. Nice answer.

Comment: I meant that you could declare the operator == template before the class template definition, then define the operator == template afterwards. Because I prefer the class definition appearing before any function that uses it, I would prefer doing it this way. I was not suggesting that you can omit the class template declaration.

Comment: @SebastianRedl: Ah I see now. I edited it to be `define or declare`. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

`operator==` is a function template, but the friendship declaration doesn't reflect this. This is one way to fix it:

```
template <class U>
friend bool operator==(const foo<U> &lhs, const foo<U> &rhs);
```

One very minor glitch is that it gives `operator==<int>` friend-access to `foo<string>`. For this reason, I think @JesseGood's fix is cleaner, albeit (paradoxically) more verbose.

Answer (score 0):

You need to specify the template types again, but different to the class template type:

```
template<typename V>
friend bool operator==(const foo<V> &lhs, const foo<V> &rhs);
```

Answer (score -2):

When overloading operators, avoid using friend functions; you'll want to define your function as a public class member, and make it take only one argument (not two).

```
template<typename T>
class foo {
  //public function allowing access to the private member t
  public:
  bool operator==(  foo<T> &rhs)
  {
      return t == rhs.t;
  }
  private:
  T t;
};


int main(int,char**) {
  foo<int> f1, f2;
  if (f1 == f2)
    ;
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: No, generally speaking you don't, because that introduces an asymmetry between the automatic conversions done for the left and right side.